# Android ListView: how to set the number of items to fill in the view

Tags: android, android-listview, layout-inflater, android-layout-weight

I was wondering if there is a way to specify how many items should fill the listview space before you need to scroll to see the others. What I mean is something like a weight to set to specify how many inflated layout should fill the listview space. Something like if I inflate 10 layouts into a listview I'd like to fill all the listview space with just 3 and then access the others 7 by scrolling so that I get all 10 items a bit bigger. Is there a way to do that? I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Sure you can do that. Takes just a little math: `int itemHeight = ListView.getHeight() / itemsPerScreen`

Comment: @Xaver Thanks for the answer but I have not really clear where I should put this string. Could you help me out plz

Comment: You don't seem to know much about `ListViews`, do you? You can set the height of the `Views` in your `ListView` in the `getView()` method of your `Adapter`.

Comment: Yeap I don't :). Thank you mate